# Autofac - Register for Transaction

Tags: c#, design-patterns, autofac, unit-of-work

Lets start with my architech. I will try to simplify my code as much as I can. If I totally mixed up, please warn me.

IUnitOfWork

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<T> : IDisposable
{
    IEntityRepository<T> Repository { get; }
    void Commit();
}
```

UnitOfWork

```
public class UnitOfWork<T> : IUnitOfWork<T>
{
    private IDbConnection _Connection;
    private IDbTransaction _Transaction;

    public IRepository<T> Repository { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(IDbConnection Connection, IRepository<T> Repository)
    {
        _Connection = Connection;
        this.Repository = Repository;
         _Transaction = _Connection.BeginTransaction();
    }
}
```

RepositoryBase

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected IDbTransaction Transaction;
    protected IDbConnection Connection { get { return Transaction.Connection; } }

    public RepositoryBase(IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        Transaction = transaction;
    }
}
```

TestDAL

```
public class TestDAL : RepositoryBase<Test>, ITestDAL
{
    public DpTestDAL(IDbTransaction transaction) : base(transaction) {}
}
```

TestService (BLL)

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private IUnitOfWork<Test> uow;
    public TestService(IUnitOfWork<Test> unitOfWork)
    {
        uow = unitOfWork;
    }
    public List<Test> GetAll()
    {
        return uow.Repository.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

And my autofac configurations.

```
builder.RegisterType<TestService>().As<ITestService>();
builder.RegisterType(typeof(OracleConnection)).As(typeof(IDbConnection)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>)).InstancePerDependency();
//builder.RegisterType(typeof(OracleTransaction)).As(typeof(IDbTransaction)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I am newbie this kind of architect and try to something my self. Please tell me if there is something wrong or totally wrong.

My problem is, I need to pass the IDbTransaction to data acess classess contructor. When I do not register IDbTransaction interface, exception is "could not resolve parameter", when I try to register with OracleTransaction the exception is "OracleTransaction" do not has a public contructor. Where did I mixed up?

Comment: The error notifies that the required params for OracleTransaction constructor are not registered. Just take a look at the constructor of the OracleTransaction type and register the missing types in the builder.

Comment: @KarthikAMR The exception saying that the oracletransaction not have a public constructor.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have one. I just checked the OracleTransaction type in MS docs. I'm posting a sample code in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

As the OracleTransaction doesn't have public constructor you can use IDbConnection to create one like below,

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
     var conn = c.Resolve<IDbConnection>();
     return conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
});
```

The above is an example of how you can register it for your use case.

Comment: This throw an "Null Reference Exception" for conn.BeginTransaction();

Comment: Is there any way to tell autofac that "you don't care this dependency I will register it at runtime" ? Because, I am resolving my transaction at my unitofwork class after connection open.